# Product custom field to enable a specific fee in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I am using [**this code from Remicorson**](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/) but its not working and I don't find where the problem is.

Here is my Code:

```
// Display Fields

add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields');

// Save Fields

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save');

function woo_add_custom_general_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Custom fields will be created here...

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => '_number_field',
        'label' => __('Environmental fee', 'woocommerce') ,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'description' => __('Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce') ,
        'type' => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => 'any',
            'min' => '0'
        )
    ));
    echo '</div>';
}

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save($post_id)
{

    // Number Field

    $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['_number_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_number_field)) update_post_meta($post_id, '_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_number_field));
}

function woo_add_cart_fee()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $prod_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_number_field', true);

    // After that you need to add condition or do calculation in.

    function add_custom_fees(WC_Cart $cart)
    {
        $fees = 0;
        $prod_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_number_field', true);
        foreach($cart->get_cart() as $item) {
            $fees+= $item['quantity'] * $prod_fee;
        }

        if ($fees != 0) {
            $cart->add_fee('Handling fee', $fees);
        }
    }

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Handling', $fee, true, 'standard');
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for creating a custom field in backend product pages and save that custom field data is working. I have just personalize it a little bit for you adding some explanations in the code:

```
 // Create and display Backend Product custom field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'ba_adding_custom_product_general_field');
function ba_adding_custom_product_general_field()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Custom fields will be created here...

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => '_number_field',
        'label' => __('Environmental fee', 'woocommerce') ,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'description' => __('Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce') ,
        'type' => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => 'any',
            'min' => '0'
        )
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}


// Save the submited data from Backend Product custom field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'ba_saving_custom_product_general_field');
function ba_saving_custom_product_general_field($post_id)
{

    // Get the submitted value
    $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['_number_field'];

    // Create/Update the submitted value in postmeta table for this product
    if (!empty($woocommerce_number_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_number_field));
}
```

And you get this in your Admin product pages *(with your custom field "Environmental fee")*:

[image]

> The problem come from your **`woo_add_cart_fee()`** as you have embed in that function a similar function, **so this will not work definitively.**

Below you will find the correct working code to add a cart fee based on that custom field calculation:

```
// Adding a custom fee to cart based on a product custom field value calculation
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'ba_custom_cart_fee');
function ba_custom_cart_fee( $cart_object ){

    // Initializing variables
    $fee = 0;

    // Iterating through each cart items
    foreach( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

        $item_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // Item Id or product ID
        $item_qty = $cart_item['quantity']; // Item Quantity

        // Getting the corresponding product custom field value
        $item_fee = get_post_meta($item_id, '_number_field', true);

        // Adding the calculation to the fee
        $fee += $item_qty *  $item_fee;
    }

    if ($fees != 0)
        $cart_object->add_fee( __('Handling fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee, true, 'standard');

}
```

Comment: if ($fees != 0)  its $fee without s...
thanks @LoicTheAztec its working perfectly..